# trelliscopejs R package only one trelliscope figure visible in html file

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, render, trellis

I am having a problem rendering more than one `trelliscopejs` displays in an html file created with Rmarkdown. I'm using `self_contained=TRUE` in order to render displays in html. The problem is that only the first display is rendered correctly: [image] whereas the rest of them is rendered as blank spaces: [image] I'm using some examples from official [tutorial](https://hafen.github.io/trelliscopejs/). The whole .rmd file is posted below:

````
---
title: "Testy trelliscopejs"
author: "balkon16"
date: "22 lipca 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE) #suppress ggplot2 warnings
```

```{r}
library(trelliscopejs)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

```{r}
library(tidyr)
library(rbokeh)

d <- mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, class) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(panel = map_plot(data,
    ~ figure(xlab = "City mpg", ylab = "Highway mpg") %>%
        ly_points(cty, hwy, data = .x)))
d
```

```{r}
d %>%
  trelliscope(name = "city_vs_highway_mpg", self_contained = TRUE)
```

```{r}
mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, class) %>%
  summarise(
    mean_city_mpg = cog(mean(cty), desc = "Mean city mpg"),
    mean_hwy_mpg = cog(mean(hwy), desc = "Mean highway mpg"),
    panel = panel(
      figure(xlab = "City mpg", ylab = "Highway mpg",
        xlim = c(7, 37), ylim = c(9, 47)) %>%
        ly_points(cty, hwy,
          hover = data_frame(model = paste(year, model),
            cty = cty, hwy = hwy)))) %>%
  trelliscope(name = "city_vs_highway_mpg", nrow = 1, ncol = 2,
              self_contained = TRUE)
```

```{r}
qplot(x = 0, y = cty, data = mpg, geom = c("boxplot", "jitter")) +
  facet_trelliscope(~ class, ncol = 7, height = 800, width = 200,
    state = list(sort = list(sort_spec("cty_mean"))), self_contained = TRUE) +
  ylim(7, 37) + theme_bw()
```
````

It seems that I'm using the newest version of `trelliscopejs` as `devtools::install_github("hafen/trelliscopejs")` returns:

```
Skipping install of 'trelliscopejs' from a github remote, the SHA1 (4be901e4) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
```

Here's my session info:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Cairo_1.5-9          bindrcpp_0.2.2       dplyr_0.7.6          ggplot2_3.0.0.9000  
[5] trelliscopejs_0.1.13 rbokeh_0.5.0         tidyr_0.8.1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] progress_1.2.0          gistr_0.4.2             tidyselect_0.2.4       
 [4] purrr_0.2.5             lattice_0.20-35         colorspace_1.3-2       
 [7] htmltools_0.3.6         yaml_2.1.19             base64enc_0.1-3        
[10] utf8_1.1.3              rlang_0.2.1             hexbin_1.27.2          
[13] pillar_1.2.2            glue_1.3.0              withr_2.1.2            
[16] pryr_0.1.4              bindr_0.1.1             plyr_1.8.4             
[19] stringr_1.3.1           munsell_0.4.3           gtable_0.2.0           
[22] devtools_1.13.5         htmlwidgets_1.2         memoise_1.1.0          
[25] codetools_0.2-15        evaluate_0.10.1         labeling_0.3           
[28] knitr_1.20              curl_3.2                Rcpp_0.12.17           
[31] scales_0.5.0            backports_1.1.2         checkmate_1.8.5        
[34] DistributionUtils_0.5-1 webshot_0.5.0           jsonlite_1.5           
[37] hms_0.4.2               digest_0.6.15           stringi_1.1.7          
[40] grid_3.5.1              rprojroot_1.3-2         cli_1.0.0              
[43] tools_3.5.1             magrittr_1.5            maps_3.3.0             
[46] lazyeval_0.2.1.9000     autocogs_0.0.1          tibble_1.4.2           
[49] crayon_1.3.4            pkgconfig_2.0.1         rsconnect_0.8.8        
[52] prettyunits_1.0.2       assertthat_0.2.0        rmarkdown_1.10         
[55] httr_1.3.1              rstudioapi_0.7          R6_2.2.2               
[58] mclust_5.4.1            git2r_0.21.0            compiler_3.5.1
```

Comment: If this is an R Markdown problem, can you provide a full R Markdown document including the YAML and chunk settings? Also, images should be uploaded with Imjur as [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @MikeyHarper I added the requested info. Could you possibly help me with the problem please?

Comment: I get this same problem when I write a post using blogdown.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works.

You need to do two things in the facet_trelliscope function:

1. Specify the path variable. For each facet_trelliscope specify one
   unique folder.
2. Set self_contained be TRUE.